# How to send a vector's content from one package to another?

Tags: java, vector, package

I am currently working on a train ticketing system (Java). One of the problems I am currently facing is how to "share" a vector between packages. I have a package login where clientList vector lives and it's purpose is to register a new user. I have another package called admin where admin duties are handled and I need to be able to visualize all the users registered. How can I handle vector clientList which belongs to login, in another package?

This is the vector in package login:

```
public class clientList {
    
    private static Vector<Client> data = new Vector<Client>();
    
    public static void addUser(Client obj) {
        data.addElement(obj);
    }
    
    public static void removeUser(int pos) {
        data.removeElementAt(pos);
    }
    
    public static Vector showUsers() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is how it adds a new user in Register Window:

```
Client obj = new Client();

            if (Client.verifyNewUser(username) == -1) {
                //Assign values-in-object
                obj.setClientUsername(username);
                obj.setClientEmail(email);
                obj.setClientId(id);
                obj.setClientPassword(password);

                clientList.addUser(obj);
```

How can I pass and parse this vector to a different class/JFrame in a different package to access its content?

Comment: What's wrong with just importing the required class from the other package?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to? I am new into Java and I know how to import, I tried it but didn't get it to work

Comment: Without the full context of your app, we can't help.  We'd need to know where your client list is instantiated and how it's accessed.  As an aside, don't use a Vector unless you absolutely need the thread safety it provides; And I highly doubt that you do.  Just use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I imported the classes from the other package to the JFrame and called the necessary methods.